# How does multiple assignment (a = b) = c syntax work?

Tags: c++, operators

How does a statement like `(a = b) = c;` work in C++, assuming `a`,`b` and `c` are `int`s or any other primitive type?

Comment: Why is it illegal in Python? Because they are all **different** programming languages! C is not C++ is not C! Why do you expect different PLs have the same semantics?

Comment: @Olaf Okay, let's forget about C, why (a = b) = c is a legal C++ syntax ? how it works ?

Comment: Can you explain why you think it shouldn't be? This question is kind of vacuous.

Comment: Taken in  context of the language questions like this sound like "Why is 2+2=4?". It is impossible to understand what you are asking about until you clarify the specific issue you have with `(a=b)=c`. Why shouldn't it work? (And `(a=b)=c` is just an expression, not a statement yet.)

Comment: That changed the question completely and leaves an answer without context! Rolled back.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: I'm not sure your change was editorial. It seems to have removed half of the question.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The OP's comment makes it clear that this was the question he wanted answered.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, it's apparently not immediately clear to OP that `(a=b)` is a valid lvalue. I guess the OP would liken it to, say, `5=a;` or  `5+b=a;` expressions that look nonsensical from how one might understand the mechanism of a procedural programming language. In layman's terms, `(a=b)` looks like an expression that can "output" a value but not "input" a value.

Comment: @nitro2k01: Quite possibly! Would like to hear the OP speak though :)

Comment: @Olaf: No, the question is about C++ and we do not put tags in titles. Please do not revert such edits. Thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I rolled back because the edit left an answer without context. Too bad your answer lost context, but you answered **after** that edit, the other was before. I followed site-rules and explicitly notified you about the rollback at your answer. See the history! You could have edited the title without chainging the question **context** (which was reason for the rollback, not the title) now leaving the other answer without context (it cites from the C standard). The editor now violated site-rules. >ou only could blame me for not editing the title **after** I rolled back!

Comment: Note: I did not CV for being opinion based; that is nonsense, as there is a clear reason they differ as I clearly stated in my first comment. Not my fault the system packs all voters together under the majority vote.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: To be consistent in complaining: please also remind the last editor! I'd edit myself, but I'm afraid I'd do something which you don't like. So you better edit yourself. I'm done here, not the time nor mood for being blamed for nothing!

Comment: @Olaf: I'm reminding you specifically because you're the one who made an erroneous claim about it in the comments! If you can't take it, don't deal it, etc....

Comment: @Olaf: _"Not my fault the system packs all voters together under the majority vote."_ I hate this too. :( [I raised it on meta years ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/172654/155739) but it's still not fixed.

Comment: @7bisso UIf I understand Kerreks answers correctly, it evaluates b and c, and assigns the result of the evaluation of c to a.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: it wasn't obvious to me that the assignment itself is a valid lvalue, now I understand that a statement like `(a = b) = c;` is roughly equivalent to `a = b; a = c;`

Comment: I'm asking you to incorporate this context into your question please :) Any time you ask why something works you should state why you reckon it shouldn't; given that it _does_ work, in general we cannot divine what your misconception is in order to correct it. (I'm not saying the question isn't sensible)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Informally, in C++, for builtin types, the result of `a = b` is a reference to `a`; you can assign a value to that reference, just as with any other reference. So `(a = b) = c` assigns the value of `b` to `a`, and then assigns the value of `c` to `a`.

For user-defined types this may not apply, although the usual idiom is for an assignment operator to return a reference to the left-hand argument, so the behavior of user-defined types mimics the behavior of builtin types:

```
struct S {
    S& operator=(const S& rhs) {
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now, `S a, b, c; (a = b) = c;` means call `a.operator=(b)`, which returns a reference to `a`; then call `S::operator=` on that result and `c`, effectively calling `a.operator=(c)`.

Comment: Results of expressions are never references. The result of `a = b` *is* the value `a` (but the side effect of changing `a` has already happened).

Comment: @KerrekSB - sigh. That's why I said "Informally". Please don't pull this down a rathole.

Comment: Yes, yes, I appreciate that... but after explaining to people twenty times and counting that rvalue references aren't rvalues, I've started to try and teach honest information from the outset, in the hope of never producing misconceptions in the first place. It's no criticism of your answer, I just wanted this detail to be recorded somewhere :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB - thank you for your input, and for deleting your comment so that my reply is out of context. Please don't pull this further down your rathole.

Comment: The answer is wrong for C. OP changed the question in-between both answers, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Olaf - the answer is not about C.

Comment: @PeteBecker: which is the problem I mentioned.

Comment: @Olaf - after you reverted the edit to the question I edited my answer to explicitly say that it refers to C++. The answer is not about C.

Comment: @PeteBecker: So my comment did what I intended (one way or the other). It does not really answer that question, but If I'd intended to DV, I'd already done. Not sure what your problem is with my comment.

Answer (score 57):

The assignment expression `a = b` is not an lvalue in C, but it is in C++:

- C11, 6.5.14 (Assignment operators):

  > An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by the left operand. An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment, **but is not an lvalue**.
- C++14, 5.18 [expr.ass] (Assignment and compound assignment operators):

  > The assignment operator (`=`) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a modifiable lvalue as their left operand **and return an lvalue** referring to the left operand.

In the evolution of C++ from C, several expressions were made "lvalue-aware", as it were, because lvalues are much more important in C++ than in C. In C, everything is trivial (trivially copyable and trivially destructible, all in the words of C++), so lvalue-to-rvalue conversions (or "lvalue conversions", as C calls them) aren't painful. In C++, copying and destruction are non-trivial concepts, and by making expressions preserve lvalue-ness, a lot of copying and destructing can be avoided that was never necessary to begin with.

Another example is the conditional expression (`a ? b : c`), which is not an lvalue in C, but can be a lvalue in C++.

Another interesting artefact of this language evolution is that C has four well-defined storage durations (automatic, static, thread-local, dynamic), but in C++ this becomes more muddled, since temporary objects are a non-trivial concept in C++ that almost calls for its own storage duration. (E.g. Clang internally has a fifth, ["full expression" storage duration](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/namespaceclang.html#a73616c07a633e772603049315dc55554).) Temporaries are of course the result of lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, so by avoiding the conversion, there's one less thing to worry about.

(Please note that all of this discussion only applies to the respective core language expressions. C++ also has the separate, unrelated feature of *operator overloading*, which produces function call expressions, which have all the usual semantics of function calls and have nothing to do with operators except for the syntax. For example, you can define an overloaded `operator=` that returns a prvalue or `void` if you so wish.)

Comment: Would `(a ? b : c) = d;` then mean that depending on the value of `a`, `d` will be assigned to `b` or `c`?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: that is [correct](https://ideone.com/CiJZzH). You can even do things like `(c ? v1 : v2).clear()`. If the conditional operator always were to result in a prvalue, then you would never be able to affect the operand values.

Comment: @KerrekSB worse, `(c ? v1 : v2).clear()` would compile fine (because we can call non-`const` functions on temporaries), but silently do nothing. _*shudders*_

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, indeed :-)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I actually wrote that for a problem on a cs test and got marked wrong.... Basically,  the TA who graded thought it was invalid c++ (didn't even check,  he just said "I don't think this is valid").

Comment: @Quentin, what means _but silently do nothing_? Would the function be called on either `v1` or `v2`, or not at all (nothing at all)?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie the function would be called on a temporary that'd be copy-constructed from either `v1` or `v2`, leaving both original objects untouched.

Comment: @Quentin, ah.....horrible!

Comment: I might go as far as to say that lvalue references are a tool designed to allow *user-defined lvalue expressions". Similarly, rvlalue references are a tool to enable arbitrary rvalue-to-lvalue conversion (which does not exist in C, and only exists otherwise as an author's tool via class member functions in C++). The value categories are the fundamental concept; references are the tools to work with value categories.

Comment: @Quentin: Try `(c ? v1 : v2).clear();` again. It actually clears the contents of the vector, not a temporary vector.

Comment: @JasonIverson Yes it does. The "would" there hinges on Kerrek's "If the conditional operator always were to result in a prvalue"; a difference between C and C++ that we're glad we have for this reason.

Comment: @JasonIverson: Sorry, the discussion went along a hypothetical tangent there. The *actual* expression will indeed clear one of the two vectors.

Comment: "In C, everything is trivial [..]" I immediately felt reminded of university math lessons :D

Answer (score 3):

`(a = b) = c` is a valid statement in C++. Here '=' is working as an assignment operator. Here, **b**'s value will be assigned to **a** and **c**'s value will be assigned to **a** for Right to Left precedence.

For example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
int c = 7;
int answer = (a = b) = c;
cout << answer << endl;
```

Output:

```
7
```

Comment: That's short on the _why_ aspect of the question, which revolves around the concept of lvalue; also, `answer` is defined, but not used.

Comment: I've just shown 'why' and 'how' this is a valid statement. Assignment operator will work for assigning and this statement is a valid for all the assignment operators. And thanks for the update about 'answer' variable.

Comment: Sorry, but someone raised on C (where the construction is illegal) will not get the _why_ from your answer. At least, I did not.

Comment: In the 2nd comment of his question he asked again _why (a = b) = c is a legal C++ syntax ? how it works ?_ For that reason I answered in this way.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a little speculation, so please correct me if I am wrong.

When they invented operator overloading, they had to come up with a standard-looking general form of an assignment operator for any class `T`. For example:

```
T& T::operator=(T);
T& T::operator=(const T&);
```

Here, it returns a reference to `T`, instead of just `T` to make three-part assignment like `x = (y = z)` efficient, not requiring a copy.

It could return a `const` reference to `T`, which would make unwanted assignment `(a = b) = c` an error. I *guess* that they didn't use this because of two reasons:

1. Shorter code - don't need to write all these `const`s all the time (the fine details of `const`-correctness were not clear at that time)
2. More flexibility - allows code like `(a = b).print()`, where `print` is a non-`const` method (because the programmer was lazy/ignorant of `const`-correctness)

The semantics for primitive types (which are not `class`es) were kind-of extrapolated, to give:

```
int& operator=(int&, int); // not real code; just a concept
```

The "return type" is not `const int&` so it matches the pattern with `class`es. So, if the buggy `(a = b) = c` code is valid for user-defined types, it should be valid also for built-in types, as required by [C++ design principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B#Philosophy). And once you document this kind of stuff, you cannot change it because of backward compatibility.